# Write own stemmer for stemming

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, stemming

I have a dataset of 27 files, each containing opcodes. I want to use stemming to map all versions of similar opcodes into the same opcode. For example: push, pusha, pushb, etc would all be mapped to push.

My dictionary contains 27 keys and each key has a list of opcodes as a value. Since the values contain opcodes and not normal english words, I cannot use the regular stemmer module. I need to write my own stemmer code. Also I cannot hard-code a custom dictionary that maps different versions of the opcodes to the root opcode because I have a huge dataset.

I think regex expression would be a good idea but I do not know how to use it. Can anyone help me with this or any other idea to write my own stemmer code?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the levenshtein distance metric - it measures the distance between two words in terms of character insertions, deletions, and replacements (so push and pusha would be distance 1 apart if you do the ~most normal thing of weighing insertions = deletions = replacements = 1 each). Based on the example you wrote, you could try just setting up categories that are all distance 1 from each other. However, I don't know if all of your equivalent opcodes will be so similar - if they're not leven might not work.

Comment: If you did want to use leven, you might want to manually look over the categories/stems it makes. It also won't work too well with words that are too short. Finally, you might be able to tune it so that it works better (ie maybe switching a letter is weighted less than adding a letter, or something similar because you have push, pusha, and posh but posh shouldn't be stemed to that group). Of course you could also combine this with other techniques (strip all ing endings or some such).